# How to properly navigate through decompiled APK code?

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering

I have decompiled an android application and open the sources with android studio.

The problem is that I can't click on import to go to the definition of the class : I have to manually go thought folder like com.appli.thing.

Do you know a good way to import some sources decompiled from jadx-gui(or other) to quickly navigate throught it ?

If you have a video/article or explanation it would be amazing !
Thanks